# SVG viewBox is not working with nested svgs at a negative position

Tags: svg, viewbox

In this example, the green circle is cut off

```
<html>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" version="1.1" style="background-color: pink" viewBox="-300 -300 500 500">
  <svg width="500" height="500" x="0" y="0"><circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" /></svg>
  <svg width="500" height="500" x="0" y="0"><circle cx="0" cy="0" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="green" /></svg>
</svg> 
</body>
</html>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/sCzZT/

Notice each circle is wrapped in its own `svg`

In this example (no nested svgs), the green circle is *not* cut off

```
<html>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" version="1.1" style="background-color: pink" viewBox="-300 -300 500 500">
   <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
   <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="green" />
</svg> 
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jVH9q/
How do I get the green circle to not get cut off when using nested svgs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The inner svg has a default viewport which is 0, 0, 500, 500 (x, y, width, height) and by default anything that overflows this area is hidden/clipped.

There are several things you could do...

1. add an overflow="visible" attribute on the inner svg elements
2. change the x, y values so that the circle is within the viewport
3. add a viewBox so that you define an explicit viewport showing the area you want to see in the inner svg.